# TornadoFX - right way to instantiate decoupled controller?

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

I have a controller which has no direct coupling to the view classes, i.e. it subscribes to events from the event bus, and nothing else.

I'm arbitrarily creating it in the View class (`by inject()`), but it really doesn't need to be there. Is there a way to tell TornadoFX that it should be created otherwise?

Comment: inject is an option, do you want a static tool to warn you? or IDE to not allow it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TornadoFX doesn't do any annotation scanning, so there is no way to add a `@Startup` annotation or anything like that. The easiest way to make sure it's instantiated is actually injecting it into your `App` subclass. That makes for a pragmatic, yet clean and maintainable approach IMO :)

EDIT: It's actually better to use `find()`, to make sure that it's actually created right away, since `inject()` is lazy.

`val ctrl = find<MyController>()`

Comment: One gotcha that I discovered is that since `by inject()` is lazy, the eventbus-only controller needs to either be referenced somewhere in the code, or injected using find. Otherwise it'll never be created and the events won't be handled.

Comment: Actually, you should just use find instead of inject in this case. I'll update my answer :)